# Cannot trade access token from authorization code

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, oauth-2.0, owin

I am currently learning an OAuth2 server of .Net and seems like OWIN provided a nice workaround to easily achieve this kind of server.

I have tried the Microsoft example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server

Seems like the sample works great, but it failed when I was trying to trade the authorization code for an access token via PostMan.

I used POST method with header `Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the following params in the request body:

```
grant_type=authorization_code
client_id=7890ab
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A50150%2Fcallback%2F
code=d7a91a351ffa4764a22ef3628c94d495443e0043bfc9405b9f1c5113a234a23d
client_secret=7890ab
```

I trace through the debugger and found out the process passed event `ReceiveAuthenticationCode` and the ticket should have been settled/Deserialized.

However no matter how I tried, the results were always invalid_grant.

---

I have looked into the original sample which I found it success to gain the access token with `WebServerClient`. But since my purpose is to provide service to not limited to .Net client, so I have to ensure I could retrieve the token without library.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

---

**Update 1**

I have connected the clientID & clientSecret to `7890ab:7890ab` and encoded the string to base 64 string `Nzg5MGFiOjc4OTBhYg==` then append to header `Authorization=Basic Nzg5MGFiOjc4OTBhYg==` which changed nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 weeks of trying, I have found that I was wrong on the basic part, I hope to save my following programmers' time who encounter this issue;

When going for the `Authorization Code` by `HTTP GET` method, the value of `redirect_uri` should be encoded (e.g `http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A50150%2Fcallback%2F`)

However, after the code is gain and going to trade for the `Access Token` by `HTTP POST` method, the value of `redirect_uri` inside the request body **should not** be encoded, the value should be `http://localhost:50150/callback/` and this is the part causes invalid_grand return.

> Notes: the value of `redirect_uri` should be same between the requests, that means if the uri is leading with `http://` or ends with a `/` when asking for the `Authorization Code`, these parts should also present when asking for the `Access Token`
>
> Reference: the following demo is way clearer than MSDN in my opinion https://github.com/yuezhongxin/OAuth2.Demo